# Proving using induction or strong induction on Fibonacci number proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm stuck on proving this statement below due to that I can't seem to find a base case that is true:

Prove that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^if(i) = f(0) - f(1) + f(2) - \cdots - f(2n-1) + f(2n) = f(2n-1)-1,$$
where $f(i)$ is the $i$th Fibonacci number.

I believe simple induction should work but I am unsure if I have to use Strong Induction.

Comment: For what $n$ do you need to prove this?

Comment: The sum looks like it should be $\sum (-1)^iF(i)$ not $F(2i)$.

Comment: why you are "unsure" about using weak or strong induction? Just try the weak induction approach, if it gets complicate try the other. So you dont need to be unsure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n+1$ we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^if(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(-1)^if(i)-f(2n+1)+f(2n+2)=\\
=f(2n-1)-1-f(2n+1)+f(2n+2)$$

but

$$f(2n+2)=f(2n+1)+f(2n),\\
f(2n+1)=f(2n)+f(2n-1)$$
so,

$$f(2n-1)-f(2n+1)+f(2n+2)=f(2n+1)$$

and then

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^if(i)=f(2n+1)-1=f[2(n+1)-1]-1$$